# .ini file in .jar fails (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Tags: java, ini4j

So i am trying to add a .ini file to my code and read it using ini4j. It works completely fine untill i try to build it into a jar, then it fails. I get the error stated above and i have no idea why. The file is in the root directory of the jar so there is no issue there.

Code where it fails:

```
Ini file = new Ini(new File(getClass().getResource("/Settings.ini").toExternalForm()));
```

Does anyone understand why this is happening and what must be done to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: `Ini file; try (InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Settings.ini")) { file = new Ini(in); }`

Comment: Thanks, that indeed solved my problem.